# storing a directed graph ( game tree )

Tags: database, tree, graph-databases

I am new to the concept of a graph db, and wondering if this is the right solution for my problem and if it is then what are the best technologies?

I am working on a game where a player can transition through N states and a graph represents all the possible states ( vertices ) and the probabilities of transitioning from one state to a new state ( edges ).

Each vertex represents a player's state. This state will contain references / pointers to all possible states into which a player can transition from this particular state and a function that calculates the probabilities for each of the states into which this player can transition ( edges ) from that current state. The function will take some properties / state of the player and will determine the probabilities.

I can code this tree very easily in say Java, but how do I store this structure in a Database so that every player coming online can query an API / server which has the entire game tree loaded and can determine how to move a player from state A to state B? Graph db?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just about any of the existing graph database products will support what you are proposing. You will simply define a set of vertices, one for each state, and encode some set of "properties" on each state and then create edges between the various states.

By using a graph database that is stored on disk (as opposed to a memory resident product) your data will be safely persisted.

A list of graph database can be found [here](https://database.guide/list-of-graph-database-management-systems/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use our graph database [Nebula](https://github.com/vesoft-inc/nebula)，it's an open-source project. As you said, the states can be vertexes and the state transition can be edges which are all supported in Nebula Graph. Welcome to use and ask questions ^^.

Answer (score 1):

what is your graph size (the count of vertices and relations)? if thousands, try jgrapht

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer, the graph size will be hundreds to maybe single thousands

Comment: https://jgrapht.org/javadoc/org/jgrapht/Graph.html I think it's enough for that size.